# Read from a compressing GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, gzipstream, http-chunked

I'm exploring how to implement an HTTP server in C#. (And before you ask, I know there is Kestrel (and nothing else that isn't obsolete), and I want a much, much smaller application.) So, the response could be a Stream that cannot be seeked and has an unknown length. For this situation, chunked encoding can be used instead of sending a Content-Length header.

The response can also be compressed with gzip or br as indicated by the client. This can be accomplished with e.g. the GZipStream class. I had almost said "easily", because that's not really the case. I always find the GZipStream API confusing each time I use it. I usually bump into every exception there is until I finally get it right.

It seems like I can only write (push) to a GZipStream and the compressed data will trickle out the other end into the specified "base" stream. But that's not desirable because I can't just let the compressed data flow to the client. It needs to be chunked. That is, each bit of compressed data needs to be prefixed with its chunk size. Of course the GZipStream cannot produce that format.

Instead, I'd like to read (pull) from the compressing GZipStream, but that doesn't seem to be possible. The documentation says it will throw an exception if I try that. But there has to be some instance that brings the compressed bytes into the chunked format.

So how would I get the expected result? Can it even be achieved with this API? Why can't I pull from the compressing stream, only push?

I'm not trying to make up (non-functional) sample code because that would only be confusing.

PS: Okay, maybe this:

```cs
Stream responseBody = ...;
if (canCompress)
{
    responseBody = new GZipStream(responseBody, CompressionMode.Compress);   // <-- probably wrong
}
// not shown: add appropriate headers
while (true)
{
    int chunkLength = responseBody.Read(buffer);   // <-- not possible
    if (chunkLength == 0)
        break;
    response.Write($"{chunkLength:X}\r\n");
    response.Write(buffer.AsMemory()[..chunkLength]);
    response.Write("\r\n");
}
response.Write("0\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: The big question is: is GZipStream compression forwards-only. If it isn't: game over, you're going to have to buffer it all (so it can write back whatever header data it needs). However, if it is forwards only, the way to look at this is with a custom underlying target stream, which deals with the buffer / transfer / release step. If this were async, System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe would be an obvious choice here as an IO pump, but I suspect GZipStream is primarily sync. Sorry, I don't have time to cover more details here, but: that's a very high level overview.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0#providers

Comment: @HansPassant That's about ASP.NET which I'm not using here for its huge size and AOT-incompatibility, not about streams.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `GZipStream` is incomplete. While your input `responseBuffer` is the correct target buffer, you have to actually write the bytes TO the `GZipStream` itself.

In addition, once you are done writing, you must close the `GZipStream` instance to write all compressed bytes to your target buffer. This is the critical step because there is no such thing as "partial compression" of an input stream in GZip. You would have to analyze the entire input in order to properly compress it. As such, this is the critical missing link that MUST happen before you can continue to write the response.

Finally, you need to reset the position of your output stream so that you can read it into an intermediary response buffer.

```
using MemoryStream responseBody = new MemoryStream();
GZipStream gzipStream = null; // make sure to dispose after use

if (canCompress)
{
    using MemoryStream gzipStreamBuffer = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    gzipStream = new GZipStream(responseBody, CompressionMode.Compress, true);

    gzipStreamBuffer.CopyTo(gzipStream);
    gzipStream.Close(); // close the stream so that all compressed bytes are written

    responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);  // reset the response so that we can read it to the buffer
}

var buffer = new byte[20];

while (true)
{
    int chunkLength = responseBody.Read(buffer);

    if (chunkLength == 0)
        break;
        
    // write response
}
```

In my test example, my `bytes` input was 241 bytes, whereas the compressed bytes written to the buffer totaled 82 bytes.

Comment: @ygoe I've updated my answer with a properly working solution.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, and I did before. The point was *not copying all content to memory* before sending it out over the network. This is what chunked encoding is about. You get a bit, send it out (with a little framing), get the next bit, send it out, but you don't know how many gigabytes are about to come.